# How do I change the icon color onHover with styling in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, icons

I have a few icons that have an initial style, `styles`.

```
<div className="w3-padding w3-xxlarge w3-text-grey">
                <a href='/About'><i className="fa fa-user-circle" style={styles.icons}></i></a>
                <a href='/Skills'><i className="fas fa-cog" style={styles.icons}></i></a>
                <a href='/Portfolio'><i className="far fa-eye" style={styles.icons}></i></a>
                <a href='/Contact'><i className="far fa-envelope" style={styles.icons}></i></a>
                </div>
```

I would like to add on hover styling such as change the color to white. I have the styling in the same file:

```
const styles = {
    icons: {
        width: '70%',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### We don't have any actions inline style

> We don't have any actions inline style like

`:hover` 
but you can use Js code

```
<div className="w3-padding w3-xxlarge w3-text-grey" >
    <a href='/About'}>
       <i className="fa fa-user-circle icon" style={styles.icons} 
      onMouseOver={({target})=>target.style.color='white'} 
      onMouseOut={(target)=>target.style.color='#00F'}>
       </i>
    </a>
</div>
```

> or the best way : you use css file and import it
>   in your css

```
.icon:hover { color:white}
```

and in your js file import it

```
 import './yourcssfile.css'
```

Comment: Putting the styling in the tag itself was easiest for me. The code broke initially, but it works when I put the onMouseOut above the onMouseOver